# Why isnt this matlab code working?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a script to remove comment lines from another script file. Here's what I tried:

```
fid = fopen('correct_answer.m');
aline = {};
counter = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
aline{counter} = fgetl(fid);
if aline{counter}(1) == '%'
    aline{counter} = '';
end
counter = counter + 1;
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
Attempted to access aline.%cell(1); index out of bounds because numel(aline.%cell)=0.

Error in hw2 (line 8)
    if aline{counter}(1) == '%'
```

If I run it without the while loop it works fine. What's up with this??
Also if you just happen to know a more simple/efficient approach to removing comment lines that would work too ;)

Comment: perhaps aline{counter} is empty. Try changing your conditional:
if ~isempty(aline{counter}) && aline{counter}(1) == '%'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you sometimes read empty lines, and you cannot access the first element of empty lines. Additionally you may have comments at the end of a valid line of code, this code should do the trick

```
fid = fopen('correct_answer.m');
aline = {};
counter = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
   aline{counter} = fgetl(fid);
   if ~isempty(aline{counter})
      k = strfind(aline{counter}, '%');
      aline{counter}(k:end) = '';   
   end
   counter = counter + 1;
end
```